amixer relationship(s) with pipewire
I have two computers (call them System A & System B); both are running a "headless" version of Debian 'bookworm'. I use both of them to play music through two Bluetooth speakers - one speaker to each computer. They both play reliably since installing pipewire. Both have Debian's latest 'stable' version of pipewire installed: 1.2.4. And if it makes any difference, I'm using mpg123 as the player on System A, and cmus on System B.
$ pipewire --version
pipewire
Compiled with libpipewire 1.2.4
Linked with libpipewire 1.2.4

I wanted to adjust the volume from the CLI - rather than fiddling with the volume controls on the BT speakers themselves. I looked into doing that with pipewire, but it seemed arcane to me.
Instead, I found this blog post from Baeldung that made sense, and it mostly worked well on System A. When I tried it on System B however, it did not seem to work at all.
'System A' and 'System B' are not identical systems, but they are quite similar; i.e. A is a Raspberry Pi Zero 2W; B is a Raspberry Pi 3A+. REF: Hardware Summaries



command
System A
System B




$ mixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joinedPlayback channels: Front Left - Front RightLimits: Playback 0 - 65536Mono:Front Left: Playback 26215 [40%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joinedPlayback channels: MonoLimits: Playback -10239 - 400Mono: Playback -1988 [78%] [-19.88dB] [on]


$ amixer info
Card default 'pipewire'/'PipeWire'Mixer name   : 'PipeWire'Components : ''Controls      : 4Simple ctrls  : 2
Card default 'Headphones'/'bcm2835 Headphones'Mixer name    : 'Broadcom Mixer'Components   : ''Controls      : 2Simple ctrls  : 1


$ amixer sset Master 90%
SPEAKER VOLUME INCREASES!Simple mixer control 'Master',0Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joinedPlayback channels: Front Left - Front RightLimits: Playback 0 - 65536Mono:Front Left: Playback 58982 [90%] [on]Front Right: Playback 58982 [90%] [on]
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0


$ amixer sset PCM 10%
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'PCM',0
NO CHANGE IN SPEAKER VOLUMESimple mixer control 'PCM',0Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joinedPlayback channels: MonoLimits: Playback -10239 - 400Mono: Playback -9175 [10%] [-91.75dB] [on]



And so there are several things I don't understand:

Why was pipewire chosen for the default card on System A, and the (Broadcomm) Headphones for System B?

Why is the Mixer control called 'Master' on System A, and 'PCM' on System B?

Why does the sset volume control have no effect on System B, yet seems to work quite well on System A?


I looked at another Q&A here on SE re "Selecting a card for amixer":

On System A: < edited >

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
--- no soundcards --- 

# and ...

$ cat /etc/asound.conf
cat: /etc/asound.conf: No such file or directory 

# and ...

$ cat /etc/alsa/conf.d/50-pipewire.conf 
# Add a specific named PipeWire pcm

defaults.pipewire.server "pipewire-0"
defaults.pipewire.node "-1"
defaults.pipewire.exclusive false
defaults.pipewire.role ""
defaults.pipewire.rate 0
defaults.pipewire.format ""
defaults.pipewire.channels 0
defaults.pipewire.period_bytes 0
defaults.pipewire.buffer_bytes 0

pcm.pipewire {

# ... etc, etc


On System B: < edited >

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
  0 [Headphones     ]: bcm2835_headpho - bcm2835 Headphones
                       bcm2835 Headphones
  1 [vc4hdmi        ]: vc4-hdmi - vc4-hdmi
                       vc4-hdmi

# and ...

$ cat /etc/asound.conf
cat: /etc/asound.conf: No such file or directory

# and ...

$ less /etc/alsa/conf.d/50-pipewire.conf
/etc/alsa/conf.d/50-pipewire.conf: No such file or directory

All that said, I am trying to gain a better understanding of how these different pieces of the sound puzzle fit together, and a method I can use to control volume from the CLI. Of course it would be preferable to have the same volume control method on both systems.

The ALSA userspace libraries that amixer uses do not necessarily access ALSA kernel devices directly – there is a layer of configuration through /etc/asound.conf (including alsalisp!) as well as plugin support for non-physical-hardware outputs.
Normally, when you install either PulseAudio or PipeWire, both provide an ALSA asound.conf snippet that loads a 'pulse' or 'pipewire' virtual output as an ALSA plugin, allowing ALSA-based programs to become PipeWire clients (and a second snippet that makes it the default output).
As PipeWire supports very dynamic routing of streams, the virtual pipewire card does not expose any controls directly related to specific physical cards – it always has just a single Master control that corresponds to the volume of the current default PipeWire sink.
Note that the latter part (making the virtual output default) is often packaged separately, especially on distributions that support both PA and PW – e.g. on Arch you have to install pipewire-alsa for 'pipewire' to become the default ALSA output.
Additionally, if you have ever written a custom ~/.asoundrc, it will override system-wide configuration – you should remove any of your old "prefer HDMI hw:X,Y" settings if you still have them.
$ cat /etc/alsa/conf.d/50-pipewire.conf
pcm.pipewire {
    type pipewire [...]
}
ctl.pipewire {
     type pipewire [...]
}

$ cat /etc/alsa/conf.d/99-pipewire-default.conf
pcm.!default {
    type pipewire
}
ctl.!default {
    type pipewire
}

(Because this works in userspace, it has no effect on /proc/asound/cards – the kernel side still has only physical outputs in /dev/snd. IIRC one used to be able to run aplay -l to list all software-recognized outputs, but even that seems to be limited to hardware devices now.)

In general, I would recommend controlling PipeWire through PulseAudio tools instead of ALSA tools. There are many volume control commands that work with the libpulse API; you might even have the standard PulseAudio pactl installed, alternatively pulsemixer, ponymix, pamixer, etc. Unlike ALSA tools, these can control volume for each PipeWire sink independently and even for individual app streams ("sink-inputs").

I've made some edits - not to change the question at all, but to add more information. Does this change your answer at all?

No, it doesn't. Your edits show that one system has /etc/alsa/conf.d/50-pipewire.conf installed and the other doesn't – that directly answers system A choosing 'pipewire' as the default ALSA output and system B not doing so (because system B is missing the file that would define that output), and that's at least one difference in installed packages that you can resolve.

I'm sorry, but the significance of your comment escapes me. First - how did etc/alsa/conf.d/50-pipewire.conf come to be installed? Second - what is the difference in installed packages that I can resolve?


Like I wrote, normally it is installed as part of PipeWire in general. 2) Use your package manager on system A to find the package which owns that file (dpkg -S, pacman -Qo, etc) and use it on system B to install that package.


But - I have pipewire (same version) installed on both systems. So why are they configured so differently??

That's still a question for your package manager on your system. Which package owns that file? Is it the base PipeWire package or is it a separate pipewire-alsa kind of subpackage? Is the same package installed on system B? Is the path in question the actual file or is it a symlink to some different file? If symlink, is it the link that's missing or is it the target that's missing? Had someone manually rm it on system B? I have no way of knowing whether someone had decided to rm that file six months ago and forgot about it.

OK - look, I get that dpkg -S /etc/alsa/... will report that pipewire "owns it". However, that file does not exist on System B. The installations of pipewire were done at approximately the same time, and in exactly the same way. There is no "someone" - there is only me, and I haven't rm'd anything.  I'm not trying to browbeat you - really I'm not - but I am trying to learn something - if I can.
